# SQL Inserting in loop using value (sysguid) multiple times

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-insert

I currently have the following script for inserting some dummy data into one of my tables for testing purposes.
I can call it and pass the number of entries I would like to have. That's working well.
Now the problem is that some of the data is not working.
The `CRecordID` should have in all three lines (12, 17, 19) the same value.

Is there a way to archive this?

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT
PROMPT inserting

INSERT INTO MySchema.MyTable (MYRECORD, TMSTAMP, SHORTRECORD, CRecordID) (
SELECT 
      '<MYRECORD>
              <TimeStamp>'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD.MM.YY')||' '||to_char(to_date('2000-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')+dbms_random.value(1,1000), 'HH24:MI:SS')||'</TimeStamp>
              <User>Test_User_1</User>
              <Application>Application1</Application>
              <Action>Dummy action text</Action>
              <INFO>dummy info text</INFO>
              <CRecordID>'||'CID_'||sys_guid()||'</CRecordID>  -- line 12
      </MYRECORD>', 
      to_date(SYSDATE,'DD.MM.YY'),
      '<SHORTRECORD>
            <User>Test_User_1</User>
            <CRecordID>'||'CID_'||sys_guid()||'</CRecordID>    -- line 17
      </SHORTRECORD>',
      'CID_'||sys_guid()                                       -- line 19
FROM DUAL connect by level <= &1
);

COMMIT;

PROMPT inserting done
```

Note: The Database is an Oracle DB.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `to_date(SYSDATE,'DD.MM.YY')` I'd rather use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`.

Comment: Right; it is kind of *stupid* applying `TO_DATE` function to `SYSDATE` which returns `DATE` datatype anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `SYS_GUID()` separately (using a CTE, for example, as in my example) and concatenate its value with your columns (I used L12 and L17 to indicate lines 12 and 17 you mentioned).

```
SQL> with gujda as
  2    (select sys_guid() guj
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 4
  5    )
  6  select 'L12_' || g.guj l12,
  7         'L17_' || g.guj l17
  8  from gujda g;

L12                                  L17
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
L12_EFB5A4947D2E4B7BBE6017E57C673ABF L17_EFB5A4947D2E4B7BBE6017E57C673ABF
L12_3E2D5B50D7C44C7FA6073A9F739687CF L17_3E2D5B50D7C44C7FA6073A9F739687CF
L12_724C21F7914B423B8CBDDC6A44AD2016 L17_724C21F7914B423B8CBDDC6A44AD2016
L12_F15D6C9865424E5C8FFFEA9C09DD6D37 L17_F15D6C9865424E5C8FFFEA9C09DD6D37

SQL>
```

Comment: As a note: WITH is not working with parenthesis - so I have to remove them form my example in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand *which* parenthesis, but - if you say so & if you made it work - fine, I'm glad you did it!